# Selecting Record fields but preserving the Record structure in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery Record field with something like this:
`publication.record.id, publication.record.price, publication.record.other_fields`

If I have a query statement: `SELECT publication.record.id, publication.record.price FROM ...`, I will get the `id` and `price` as the returned field names.

Is there a way I could reserving the original RECORD structure? Basically, if my output is JSON, I'd like to still have:

```
[
  {
    "publication": {
      "record": {
        "id": 123
        "price: 50.0
      }
  }
]
```

rather than:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123
    "price": 50.0
  }
]
```

I could do `SELECT publication FROM ...` and got what I needed, but that would include ALL fields in publication rather than just `id, price`.

Is there a way to select specific fields in a Record yet reserving its structure?

Thanks.

Linh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this like below:

```
SELECT struct (struct(publication.record.id , publication.record.price) as record) 
as publication   FROM `your_table`
```

Comment: Thanks rtbf, that works well! With this solution, I would have to reconstruct the RECORD structure in the SELECT. If the RECORD structure is complex, that could be some work involved. Is there some flag telling BigQuery to reserve original structure?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to keep some of the structure without renaming etc. then you just can leave some levels without going deeper. It works on any level.